# What is the origin of 'many a [singular noun]'?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the weird phrase 'many a [singular noun]'? It's extremely odd: for one thing, 'many' here is a predeterminer (very unusual), for another, it goes with a singular noun. What is the explanation for this bizarre structure?

*additional question you may not answer: Is it stylistically neutral? How would it sound to a native speaker's ear? Isn't it something literary?*

Comment: English is quirky and  this is one of its throwbacks. Today, it's regional or used in aphorisms.

Comment: That’s just reminded me that there’s a song from Oklahoma! that begins “Many a new day ...”

Comment: It's not just *"many a".* Walt Whitman: *Many the burials, many the days and nights, passing away,* Henry Wadsworth Longfellow: *Many the souls that sped, Many the hearts that bled, By our stern orders.*

Comment: But according to the OED, *many a* goes back to the 13th century (not long after *a* entered English), while *many the* isn't even mentioned—I expect it's an invention of poets who used *many a* as a model.

Comment: Comedy of Errors, the Bard: "Why, but there's many a man hath more hair than wit". There are tons of "many a" in Shakespeare.

Comment: Henry IV, Part One: I can speak English, lord, as well as you;
For I was train'd up in the English court;
Where, being but young, I framed to the harp//
Many an English ditty lovely well//
And gave the tongue a helpful ornament,
A virtue that was never seen in you. [Oh god, he was funny.]

Comment: My question is about the phrase's origin, the other question is about how it's different from a similar structure. @tchrist, please reopen.

Comment: Before I go read the linked answer let me aay that Ger *viele `GEN.` der Männer*"many of the man" is quite usual, though *manch einer, mancher einer* "many an" is as idiomatic as *so mancher* "so many; some, `pl.` some" and *einige* "some" (literally *any*, OE *aenic*).